# Python bindings using pybind11 with std::filesystem as function argument giving TypeError

Tags: c++17, pybind11, std-filesystem

I have a class Foo() and class Foo() has a function with the following declaration:

`bool Foo::copyFile(const std::filesystem::path& src, const std::filesystem::path& dest)`

The requirement is that the class Foo should have Python bindings. I am using pybind11 to create the Python bindings.

I have written the following to create the Python bindings:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include "Foo.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(TestModule, m) {
     py::class_ <Foo>(m, "Foo")
        .def(py::init())
        .def("copyFile",&Foo::copyFile);
};
```

This compiles OK and I am able to create the Python bindings pyd file.
When I use the Python bindings for class Foo using:

```
from TestModule import Foo

f = Foo()
ret = f.copyFile("C:\Users\csaikia\Downloads\testfile_src", "C:\Users\csaikia\Downloads\testfile_dest")
```

it gives a TypeError. I suspect that it has something to do with pybind11 support for std::filesystem in c++17 since I did not see this happening with other functions of the class that has `std::string` or `std::vector`.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: copyFile(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: TestModule.Foo, arg0: std::filesystem::path, arg1: std::filesystem::path) -> bool

Invoked with: <TestModule.Foo object at 0x0000000002A33ED8>,  'C:\\Users\\csaikia\\Downloads\\testfile_src', 'C:\\Users\\csaikia\\Downloads\\testfile_dest'

Did you forget to `#include <pybind11/stl.h>`? Or <pybind11/complex.h>,
<pybind11/functional.h>, <pybind11/chrono.h>, etc. Some automatic
conversions are optional and require extra headers to be included
when compiling your pybind11 module.
```

I am new to pybind11. Can someone please help how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my conversation with the pybind11 devs:

"Pybind has no idea how to convert a `py::str` to `std::filesystem::path`. There's no available caster nor has the `std::filesystem::path` class been bound.

The easiest way would be to not bind `Foo::copyFile` directly. Instead bind a lambda that accepts `const Foo&` and `const std::string&` as parameters and then you can pass `std::string` to `copyFile` where `std::filesystem::path` is expected, letting C++ implicit conversion take place.

You can maybe also do `py::class_<std::filesystem::path>` and make a binding for the `std::string` convertor and then use `py::implicitly_convertible` to let all that C++ implicit construction happen on python side, but... meh, too much work."

It works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the following lines to your bindings (assuming `py::module& m`).

```cpp
py::class_<std::filesystem::path>(m, "Path")
    .def(py::init<std::string>());
py::implicitly_convertible<std::string, std::filesystem::path>();
```

This is based on the latter approach described by @user304255.